# Does MaxLength data annotation work with List<T>?

Tags: c#, list, data-annotations, maxlength

One can use `[MaxLength()]` attribute with strings and simple arrays:

***i.e.***:

```
[MaxLength(500)]
public string ProductName { get; set; }
```

Or

```
[MaxLength(50)]
public string [] Products { get; set; }
```

But can it be used with a List?

***i.e.***:

```
[MaxLength(50)]
public List<string> Types { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looking at the source code, it depends on which .NET version is being used.

- In .NET framework, it attempts to cast the object as `Array`. Therefore, if it isn't (e.g., `List<T>`), an InvalidCastException will be raised. ([source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/MaxLengthAttribute.cs,69))
- In .NET Core, [it calls a method](https://source.dot.net/#System.ComponentModel.Annotations/System/ComponentModel/DataAnnotations/MaxLengthAttribute.cs,81) named `TryGetCount()` which attempts to cast as `ICollection` and if that fails, it uses reflection to get the `Count` property. Therefore, it should work on any object that implements `ICollection` (which `List<T>` does) or any object with an `int Count` property. ([source](https://source.dot.net/#System.ComponentModel.Annotations/System/ComponentModel/DataAnnotations/MaxLengthAttribute.cs,120))

Obviously, in both cases, it first checks if the object is a string before going after a collection.

***Note:** The same goes for [`MinLength` data annotation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.minlengthattribute).*