# Does the MinLengthAttribute apply for dictionaries too?

Tags: c#, .net-core, data-annotations

I have a .Net Core 3.1 app and want to make sure a dictionary contains at least one pair. The docs say the data annotation `MinLength` applies for strings and arrays

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.minlengthattribute?view=net-3.1

```
[MinLength(1)]
public Dictionary<T, V> MyDictionary { get; set; }
```

Do I have to create my own validation attribute or does the code above work fine for dictionaries?

I made a little test by creating a Web API project and modified the sample controller

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<TheQueryFields> Get([FromQuery] TheQueryFields theQueryFields)
    {
        return Ok(theQueryFields);
    }
}

public class TheQueryFields
{
    [MinLength(1)]
    public Dictionary<string, string> Collection { get; set; }
}
```

Calling this endpoint with `https://localhost:44306/weatherforecast` does not return a 400, the validation passes.

So it seems for dictionaries I have to create my own validation attribute?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does MaxLength data annotation work with List<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67433642/does-maxlength-data-annotation-work-with-listt)

Comment: The linked post is about generic lists but as I mentioned in my answer there, in .NET Core, a method named `TryGetCount()` is used to determine the collection count. Bottom line: yes, it should work with dictionaries as well.

Comment: but why did my test fail then? The request should get rejected with a 400 then

Comment: there is no need for it. When changing the datatype to `string` it sends back a 400

Comment: Okay, you're going to need to provide a [repro]. For me, [it works exactly as expected](https://i.imgur.com/8XRnD4y.gif) whether it's a string or a dictionary property.

Comment: Note that if you don't pass any values for `Collection` (meaning that it's null), the validation _will pass_. This is also true for the string property. If it's null, the validation will pass. So, `MinLength(1)` is actually meaningless if the property is null. If you need to ensure that the property gets a value (be it a string, a dictionary, or any nullable property), you should use `[required]` instead.

Answer (score 3):

`MinLenghAttribute`, checks in the decorated field for either a `Length` property (in case of `string` or `Array`) or for a `Count` property (`Dictionary`, `List` and other collections).

You can peek the reference source implementation here: [MinLengthAttribute](https://source.dot.net/#System.ComponentModel.Annotations/System/ComponentModel/DataAnnotations/MinLengthAttribute.cs,0438bdf9cc2f83ce)

However, as pointed by @41686d6564 in the comments, this validator ignores if you pass a `null` value, and just return `True`.

Therefore, the simpler approach would be to use `MinLenghAttribute` together with `RequiredAttribute`.

```
[Required, MinLengh(1)]
public Dictionary<T, V> MyDictionary { get; set; }
```

On the other hand, It is pretty straightforward to implement a custom validator. Here is an example that validates a collection is not empty or null:

```
    // NotEmpty validates that a collection or string is not null or empty.
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Parameter)]
    public sealed class NotEmptyAttribute : ValidationAttribute {
        const string ValidationError = "The field {0} must be a non-empty collection.";

        public NotEmptyAttribute() : base(ValidationError) { }

        public override bool IsValid(object value) => value is IEnumerable e && e.Cast<object>().Any();
    }
```

And you can use it like this:

```
[NotEmpty]
public Dictionary<T, V> MyDictionary { get; set; }
```

Comment: As commented above, the same source you linked to shows that [it checks for the `Count` property](https://source.dot.net/#System.ComponentModel.Annotations/System/ComponentModel/DataAnnotations/MinLengthAttribute.cs,64) (and it does so by first checking if the object is an `ICollection` which a `Dictionary` is). See my answer to the linked question for more. Bottom line: there's no need for a custom attribute.

Comment: You might be right. Let's see if the OP provides additional information on why it is not working.